# Getting "People talking about this" metric (PTAT)

Tags: facebook, metric

I'm using the facebook api to pull some metrics, I want to get the "talking about this" metric, I reviewd the "Stories and People talking about this" from the facebook api and I'm pulling the "page_storytellers" metric, but I see that the number from this metric does not match with the "talking about this" metric from the facebook original page.

My question here is

How does the facebook api calculate this value for (page_storytellers metric)? 
The "page_storytellers" metric is the correct one to get the "talking about this metric"?

Thanks for your help

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm interested in calculation page_storytellers metric to get the PTAT...

Answer (score 6):

In the Facebook Graph API Explorer there is a description for **talking_about_count** field:

> The number of people that are talking about this page (last seven days). No access token or user `access_token`. `number`

So **talking_about_count** field is equal to **page_storytellers** insight metric with week period.

Comment: Facebook describes this only at the graph docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ not the FQL docs, damn.. Thanks though.

Comment: I tried the same.But it returns 0 as the talking_about_count.I tried the following.
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id?fields=fan_count,talking_about_count&access_token=accessToken.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

you just need to target the graph api node for the page

https://graph.facebook.com/nike/

last metric (`talking_about_count`) is talking about this. pull the number from the JSON object.

change "nike" with the page id you want to collect data from.