# facebook graph api returns null for page_storytellers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Hello i'm using the facebook graph api to pull some metrics but in recent days the api returns null values for some of them

ie : id/insights/page_storytellers

```
    {
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/id/insights/page_storytellers?suppress_http_code=1&since=1405894077&until=1406153277", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/id/insights/page_storytellers?suppress_http_code=1&since=1406412477&until=1406671677"
  }
}
```

My access token has the required permissons (read insights)

> *edit : page_storytellers was deprecated on July 2 breaking changes but is there a comparable metric to return?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think when you said that `page_storytellers` was deprecated, you meant "PTAT"/"People Talking About This", right?  That's what I see in the breaking changes at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/pages-api-changes-2014-07-02

Answer (score 1):

Two years later...but in case anyone happens across this, this may help:

I think the only way is to sum the values of the metric **page_storytellers_by_story_type**.

```
{
  "name": "page_storytellers_by_story_type",
  "period": "days_28",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": {
        "other": 4425,
        "fan": 2946,
        "page post": 95,
        "user post": 0,
        "checkin": 0,
        "question": 0,
        "coupon": 0,
        "event": 0,
        "mention": 0
      },
      "end_time": "2016-02-26T08:00:00+0000"
    },
    "title": "28 Days Talking About This By Story Type",
    "description": "28 Days: The number of people talking about your Page, by story type. (Unique Users)",
    "id": "123456789/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/days_28"
}
```

totalling "other, fan, page post, etc..." will give the total storytellers.

Answer (score 0):

The comparable metric seems to be the `talking_about_count` metric on the Graph object for the page itself.

See this answer (and the other answers on the same page) for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973361/114558

I believe this is the number of people "talking about this" page over the last 7 days.

Of course, since this data is not available through the Insights endpoint, no historical data is available.  To get a historical number, you'd have to access the endpoint every day and store it.